# Generated link `/foo` for `_collection/foo.md` doesn't work work locally (but does on Github Pages)

Tags: jekyll, github-pages

I have the following file structure in my Jekyll project:

```
├── _articles
│   ├── bar
│   │   └── widget.md
│   ├── bar.md
│   └── phone.md
└── foo.md
```

See here: https://github.com/janpio/jekyll-test

`_articles` is a collection that is defined in `_config.yml`:

```
collections:
  articles:
    title: Articles
    output: true
    permalink: :path
```

On Github Pages this is built into these URIs:

1. https://janpio.github.io/jekyll-test/bar/widget
2. https://janpio.github.io/jekyll-test/bar
3. https://janpio.github.io/jekyll-test/phone
4. https://janpio.github.io/jekyll-test/foo/

See here: https://janpio.github.io/jekyll-test/

That is all fine and as expected.

---

But when I `bundle exec jekyll s` this project locally<sup>1</sup> it doesn't work the same way. I get the expected URIs:

1. http://127.0.0.1:4000/bar/widget
2. http://127.0.0.1:4000/bar
3. http://127.0.0.1:4000/phone
4. http://127.0.0.1:4000/foo/

But the problem is that #2 gets redirected to `127.0.0.1:4000/bar/` and shows a directory listing instead of the actual page!

Looking at `_site` this is the file structure that is generated:

```
├── bar
│   └── widget.html
├── bar.html
├── foo.html
├── index.html
└── phone.html
```

So I can access `bar.md` at `http://127.0.0.1:4000/bar.html`.

How can I fix this?

---

<sup>1</sup> My Gemfile is so the environment should be identical to Github Pages: https://github.com/janpio/jekyll-test/blob/master/Gemfile

---

### Update for Jekyll 3.6.x

The [3.6.0 Jekyll release changed this behaviour](https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll/releases/tag/v3.6.0):

> Fix serving files that clash with directories ([#6222](https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll/issues/6222)) ([#6231](https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll/pull/6231))

Unfortunately, these changes didn't really fix the problem but replace it with a less serious one: The link now [doesn't show the directory listing any more but the correct page](https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll/issues/6222#issuecomment-338384344), but the path is still different in that it adds the `/` at the end. Unfortunately as a regression [`bar/widget` doesn't render the correct content any more but shows `bar.md`](https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll/issues/6459).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Update for Jekyll 3.7.x

The 3.7.0 Jekyll release included a PR that should fix this problem: 
[return correct file in dir if dir has same name as file](https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll/pull/6569)

Answer (score 1):

These are the first solutions that come to my mind:

1. Stop using 'pretty URLs'
2. Use only index.md files (each of them in a seperate folder)
3. Prevent naming collisions between folders and files
4. Create an index.html file in the bar folder that redirects to bar.html (although that might create a redirect loop)

Comment: Thanks, I will look into these suggestions, they all seem to be valid workarounds. But do you know _why_ this is different locally than on Github Pages?

Comment: If you are still interested: See the update on my question. Stuff is getting improved.